# JavaScript read JSON to store in different variables

Tags: javascript, json

I am sure this is a simple question, but I have a SuperWebSocket server which links to a HTML5 client. I push a number of differently structured JSON messages to the client, but each JSON message has a "Type" member, and the JSON messages are one at a time and not nested.

So what I am unsure about is how I can read from the JSON string to determine the Type member and then store in a specific variable.

This is pseudocode, (and I am most used to VB) and I am wondering if anyone can help me convert it to a javascript equivalent

var obj = JSON.parse(ev.data);

if obj.Type = "A" then
'do task A
elseif obj.Type = "B" then
'do task B
elseif obj.Type = "C" then
'do task C
end if

Also with javascript, should I be destroying the object after use?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (obj.Type==='A') {
     // do task a
} else if (obj.Type==='B') {
     // do task b
} else {
     // do whatever
}
```

I believe that once the object goes out of scope that Javascript will collect and dispose.

good luck.

Comment: @AnuragPeshne I believe that `obj.Type` is a custom property name .

Comment: Thanks Guys, Admittedly I broke one of the conventions in using Type rather than a better name like MessageType but appreciate the help!

Comment: If `obj.Type` is not a custom property name then consider using `typeof` operator to test for native data types.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not a strongly typed language so you can assign any item to an object.  You can use the keyword `typeof` to determine the type of variable if need be.  [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Be warned, however that checking for types in JavaScript is also tricky.  For example `(null === undefined)` is false, but `(null == undefined)` is true.

Food for architectural thought: You should know the kind of data structure you are expecting back from the server and would therefore make the typeof check moot.  Consider solutioning the client-side to call different functions for different tasks when a successful return of an JSON object occurs for specific tasks.